# How to select next column when previous column meets certain condition using SQL

Tags: sql, select, impala

I'm using SQL on Impala

The table I'm querying on looks like

customer name   shop1   shop1number shop2   shop2number shop3   shop3number

TOM AB  111 AA  231 AC  321

AMY AC  121 AB  213 AD  231

Franck  AD  123 AE  233 AB  234

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0iY7.png)
here, the numbers are customer loyalty number and the challenge is if I'm looking for the loyalty number of shop 1 (AB), I have no idea which column it falls in as when customer fills in their loyalty number, it's their choice to put in the number at whatever order they profile

Comment: Please can you make the table design a little clearer? Perhaps provide a picture?

Comment: Is this 3 rows? `Shop 1/ AAA/shop 2/BBB/ shop 3/CCC` or a single column on a single row?

Comment: No that's one row with 6 columns, so the table looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you are looking for all the loyalty numbers associated with a shop, so one way could be  to bring rows data to columns first using `union all` and then search for a shop; lets say `AB`.

```
select * from
(
select customername, shop1 as shop, shop1number as shopnumber
from table1
union all
select customername, shop2 as shop, shop2number as shopnumber
from table1
union all
select customername, shop3 as shop, shop3number as shopnumber
from table1
    ) t
where t.shop = 'AB';
```

**Result:**

```
+--------------+------+------------+
| customername | shop | shopnumber |
+--------------+------+------------+
| AMY          | AB   |        213 |
| TOM          | AB   |        111 |
| Franck       | AB   |        234 |
+--------------+------+------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZPXLH38107)**

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @shop varchar(10)
set @shop='AB'
select cname, 
case when  shop1=@shop then shop1 
when shop2=@shop then shop2
when shop3=@shop then shop3
end
as shop, 
shop1number as shopnumber
from tblcus
```